# Выпадающее меню через select

Tags: php, html

Как сделать чтоб при выборе какого-то пункта в списке, например, 1, рядом с ним стоящий текст менялся на другой, например, "Текст2!"

***Список***

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select> <option>1</option>
<option>2</option> <option>3</option>
</select> </form>
```

Текст, который должен именятся

```
<h1>Текст!</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если без перезагрузок, то это можно сделать с помощью JS. Вот [простейший пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ML8DL/) с использованием jQuery или [на чистом JS](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ML8DL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Файл должен быть php-файлом, не html.

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
     <select> <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>    <option>3</option> </select> 
     <input type='submit' name="sub" value="изменить!" />
   </form>
   <?php
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])){
      echo "<h1>Текст2</h1>";
    } else echo "<h1>Текст1</h1>";
    ?>
```

Но лучше делать как подсказал Deonis